# How can I manipulate HTML elements which are added during the runtime?

Tags: javascript, html

The code im working on first makes a call to the database. Through this call, it is determined wether there are available workstations in the office or not.
If there are available workstations, "option" elements are added to a "select" element. This is achieved via jquery:

```js
$('#idofselectelement').html(data)
```

Where "data" represents the markup to be inserted into the "select" element.

Now, my problem is that I'm trying to implement some code which checks wether your "favorite workstation" is available in the selected timeframe and then automatically preselects the respective workstation from the dropdownmenu in the "select" element. Everything is working so far, except for the selection of the workstation from the dropdown menu :/
The part of 
I'm rather new to programming with javascript and the HTML DOM, so I'm not sure whether the fact that the options im trying to chose from are added during the runtime?

The code I've tried to manipulate the dropdown menu with is like this:

```html
$('#idofselectelement').val(favoriteworkstation);
```

However, as I said, this doesn't work. 
I've also already tried to output (console.log) the select element's length property right after the code which adds the markup with the available options has run.
But according to the output Im getting, the length is zero Oo 
However, the dropdownmenu is definitely being created AND I can indeed manipulate it, but unfortunately not in the way I want to.
If I add an onclick event which sets the value of the respective select element, then the value in the select field indeed changes to the value specified in the event handler. 
So I wonder why I can't have the favorite workstation preselected after the timeframe was chosen...

EDIT:
For further insight into the problem, I'm adding a bit more code here.
This is what the HTML Select element looks like BEFORE anything is added during the runtime:

```html
<label for="#sitz">Sitz Nr.</label>
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="sitz" name="sitz" value="">
```

the markup which is added during the runtime

```html
<option>workstationvalue</option>
<option>workstationvalue</option>
//and so on, depending on the situation...
```

Comment: Can you post your code in its entirety please?

Comment: what do you mean by "entirety"?
Unfortunately I cant copypaste my code, because the sources are on a VM and I cant copy from there...

Furthermore, If I had to post the entire code, it would be huge...

Comment: I guess you are using `$.ajax` to get the data from the BE? So in your success/done callback you are probably building your html. Or does the server already send you the html? Where do you get the favorite workstation from in relation to the available workstations?(same call, call after, parallel call,....)

Comment: There is no ajax used, the data from the php is brought into javascript via 

"var foo = <?php echo ... ?>"
inside php, the database calls are made via PDO object.

Yes, in case there are available workstations, the html is generated inside the php code (via: echo "MARKUP") and added to the respective "select" element. 
So I guess you could say that the server sends me the html. 

The favorite workstation is  fetched from the database, using the ID of the logged User. After this, the reservations for this workstation are fetched from the database and are compared against the sel time

Answer (score 0):

This is a timing issue.

The js trying to find the element is faster than the actual add of the element to DOM.

Can you describe what you want to do? You might be able to do that before adding the element to DOM.

Editing before adding to DOM is possible if you convert your String to an jQuery object

```
var $jqueryObject = $(data);
$jqueryObject.find('.classYouSearch').val(value);
$('.whereToAd').html($jqueryObject);
```

Comment: Yeah I already had suspected the runtime as well. 
In my console log, the logs from the functions doing the comparison and selection are printed before the logs printing out the added markup.
In my code, the functions adding the markup are called before the functions doing the comparisons and selection, so I wondered whether the unexpected output in the console.log is due to some lag in the console.log function (as I said, Im a newbie...^^).

Comment: Description of what I want to do:
After the timeframes have been chosen from datepickers (jquery), the functions preparing the selection field are called. These add the markup, as I described. After this call, a function doing the comparison between the chosen date and the dates saved inside the reservations for the respective workstation is called. This function then also shall select the favorite workstation from the dropdown menu, which at least according the "chronological order" of the code should be the case AFTER the function preparing the HTML has run...

Comment: ok i guess i understand. did you try to "select" before adding to the DOM (as mentioned in my answer?)

Comment: Yes, this is probably whats happening. And if it were possible to just "halt" the function doing the selection for a moment, so that the html can be added before the selection is executed, then I would do it...^^

Comment: just to proove its an timing issue you could do an setTimeout for a short time, but this in no good way for a productiv system